# How to remove doubles by nested attributes in Python?

Tags: python, loops

I've got a list of records in which the details contain some doubles. In the list of dicts below you see that the first 3 records (with id 1, 2 and 3) have the same "count" for all the details with a dir "s" (even though their respective detail id's differ). I would like to remove all records from the root list, for which all the counts of the details with a dir "s" are the same as the counts of the details with a dir "s" in a previous record. So from the list below I would want the records with ids 2 and 3 to be removed from the records list.

I've been writing nested loops for a while, but I can't really find a way of doing this. Plus, my code constantly becomes this complete mess real quick.

What would be a logical and Pythonic way of doing this?

```
records = [
    {
        'id': 1,
        'details': [
            {"id": 10, "dir": "s", "count": "1"},
            {"id": 20, "dir": "u", "count": "6"},
            {"id": 30, "dir": "s", "count": "1"}
        ]
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'details': [
            {"id": 40, "dir": "s", "count": "1"},
            {"id": 50, "dir": "u", "count": "7"},
            {"id": 60, "dir": "s", "count": "1"}
        ]
    },
    {
        'id': 3,
        'details': [
            {"id": 70, "dir": "s", "count": "1"},
            {"id": 80, "dir": "u", "count": "8"},
            {"id": 90, "dir": "s", "count": "1"}
        ]
    },
    {
        'id': 4,
        'details': [
            {"id": 100, "dir": "s", "count": "999"},
            {"id": 110, "dir": "up", "count": "6"},
            {"id": 120, "dir": "s", "count": "999"}
        ]
    },
]
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: if  `{'id':4,'details':[{"id":200,"dir":"s","count":"123"},{"id":201","dir":"s","count":"321"}]}`,  `{'id':5,'details':[{"id":202,"dir":"s","count":"123"},{"id":203","dir":"s","count":"321"}]}` and  `{'id':6,'details':[{"id":204,"dir":"s","count":"321"},{"id":205","dir":"s","count":"123"}]}` were in `record`, would any get deleted?  Why?

Answer (score 0):

Use a set and the key based on the two elements of the dict that you consider the definition of a 'duplicate'.

Simple example to uniquify:

```
seen=set()
for di in records:
    for sdi in di['details']:
        key=(sdi['dir'], sdi['count'])
        if key not in seen:
            seen.add(key)
            print(sdi)
        else:
            # deal with the duplicate?
            pass
```

Prints:

```
{'id': 10, 'dir': 's', 'count': '1'}
{'id': 20, 'dir': 'u', 'count': '6'}
{'id': 50, 'dir': 'u', 'count': '7'}
{'id': 80, 'dir': 'u', 'count': '8'}
{'id': 100, 'dir': 's', 'count': '999'}
{'id': 110, 'dir': 'up', 'count': '6'}
```

Giving a first pass the what I *think* you mean:

```
seen=set()
new_rec=[]
for di in records:
    new_di={}
    new_di['id']=di['id']
    new_li=[]
    for sdi in di['details']:
        key=(sdi['dir'], sdi['count'])
        if key not in seen:
            seen.add(key)
            new_li.append(sdi)
        else:
            # deal with the duplicate?
            pass
    new_di['details']=new_li
    new_rec.append(new_di)
```

Which results in:

```
[   {   'id': 1,
        'details': [   {   'id': 10,
                           'dir': 's',
                           'count': '1'},
                       {   'id': 20,
                           'dir': 'u',
                           'count': '6'}]},
    {   'id': 2,
        'details': [   {   'id': 50,
                           'dir': 'u',
                           'count': '7'}]},
    {   'id': 3,
        'details': [   {   'id': 80,
                           'dir': 'u',
                           'count': '8'}]},
    {   'id': 4,
        'details': [   {   'id': 100,
                           'dir': 's',
                           'count': '999'},
                       {   'id': 110,
                           'dir': 'up',
                           'count': '6'}]}]
```